# Recreating JavaScript Google Calendar API authentication in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api

Google has provided this document to explain how to migrate from GAPI to GIS, but being new to Vue, I'm struggling with figuring out how to divide JavaScript into the appropriate blocks. https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#server-side-web-apps

Below is my attempt, that I took from the GIS only section of the migration doc, but I receive an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestAccessToken')`

```js
<template>
    <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization Token model</h1>
    <button @click="getToken()">Get access token</button><br><br>
    <button @click="loadCalendar()">Load Calendar</button><br><br>
    <button @click="revokeToken()">Revoke token</button>

</template>

<script>
    var client
    var access_token

    
    export default {
        
        methods:{
            initClient() {
                client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: '...',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
                        https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
                callback: (tokenResponse) => {
                    access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
                },
                });
            },
            getToken() {
                client.requestAccessToken();
            },
            revokeToken() {
                google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
            },
            loadCalendar() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
                xhr.send();
            }
    }
    }
</script>
```

In the index.html file I have placed:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>
```

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the gsi script in your `index.html` and calling `initClient` in the `onload` function. It's obvious that there's no way Vue will call your `initClient` function from `index.html` as this function is defined in your component. So:

- Remove `script` tag from `index.html`
- Load the gsi script in your Vue component
- (Bonus) add a check in your component to only render buttons if the `client` is loaded.

##### Updated Code (comments added):

```
<template>
  <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization Token model</h1>

  <!-- Here we are going to restrict buttons until our client is loaded -->
  <template v-if="!client">
    <button @click="getToken()">Get access token</button><br /><br />
    <button @click="loadCalendar()">Load Calendar</button><br /><br />
    <button @click="revokeToken()">Revoke token</button>
  </template>
  <span v-else>Loading Google APIs</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // Move the variables in data
  data() {
    return {
      client: null,
      access_token: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    initClient() {
      // Update reference from client to this.client
      this.client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: "...",
        scope:
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
           https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
          // Update reference from access_token to this.access_token
          this.access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
        },
      });
    },
    getToken() {
      // Update reference from client to this.client
      this.client.requestAccessToken();
    },
    revokeToken() {
      // Update reference from access_token to this.access_token
      google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(this.access_token, () => {
        console.log("access token revoked");
      });
    },
    loadCalendar() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events");
      // Update reference from access_token to this.access_token
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.access_token);
      xhr.send();
    },
    
    // Here we are loading the script
    loadGsiScript() {
      const gsiScript = document.createElement("script");
      gsiScript.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
      gsiScript.async = true;
      gsiScript.defer = true;

      // We need to link our initClient here
      gsiScript.onload = this.initClient;
      document.head.appendChild(gsiScript);
    },
  },

  // Once HTML document is ready Vue will call our loadGsiScript function
  mounted() {
    this.loadGsiScript();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This kind of looks like a chatGPT answer. If you're not aware, chatGPT is strictly banned. Please read [chatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Looking at your other answers it is obvious you don't need chatGPT.

Comment: Thanks @u-dev.
There's an issue with `this.client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({`


`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined at Proxy.init`


Is that to do with the order in which google is loaded?

Comment: @StevenDiffey I have updated the code, can you please check now?

Comment: Thanks so much @U-Dev I think we're close, but I'm getting a 401 error for some reasons. Is there a way to validate that the token is created successfully?

Comment: Thanks so much @U-Dev
Yeah - I hadn't realised that the script wouldn't be loaded.